# Importing a package installed with anaconda in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I want to work with the python package [holopy](https://holopy.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.1/users/install.html). Apparently you have to use conda to install it, so I first installed Anaconda 4.2.0 (since I'm using Python 3.5). I opened the virtual environment I normally use and installed holopy as they recommend on the official site:

```
conda install -c conda-forge holopy
```

Afterwards, when in the virtual environment I type `conda list`, holopy shows up. But when I type `python3` and then `import holopy`, it says package not found. It does however work when I leave the virtual environment. I need it in the virtual environment though, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how well anaconda and virtual environments i.e.`venv` work together. If you're using anaconda anyway then I highly recommend using anaconda environments. Please go through this short tutorial about [anaconda environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) - you won't regret it.

#### Why it didn't work for you?

The `conda` command is available only in the base anaconda environment. So when you run the command - `conda insall -c conda-forge holopy`, it installed `holopy` in the base anaconda environment and it won't be available to you in your `venv`.

After looking at the documentation of `holopy` it seems probable that when they said `virtual environment` they actually meant `anaconda virtual environment`. Therefore the solution is to first create an `anaconda virtual environment` called `holopy-env` and then run the command `conda install -n holopy-env -c conda-forge holopy`.

### A better way of doing things with Anaconda

I will also give you a quick and clean example of how to create an environment using anaconda. If you're using Anaconda then it would be wise to use it's [environment management](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) tools. Create an `environment.yml` file with the following contents:

#### environment.yml using conda-forge/holopy & python 3.6

```
name: holopy-env      # any name for the environment
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:         # everything under this, installed by conda
- python=3.6
- holopy
- pip:                # everything under this, installed by pip
  - future
```

#### How to install the environment?

`conda create --force -f environment.yml`

#### How to activate the environment?

`source activate opencv-env`

#### After activating the environment

- You should be able to `import holopy`
- Install pip packages using `pip install <package>`
- Install conda packages using `conda install -n holopy-env -c CHANNEL <package>`

Comment: Thanks! So complicated.. actually It seems that I asked the wrong question. I don't want to work with anaconda but it is the only way to install the holopy package. After installing anaconda and then holopy, I couldn't import it in Eclipse with pyDev because I usually work in a `venv`. However I manually added the anaconda python path in eclipse, and now I can import holopy there.

Comment: I just found a short tutorial on how to use pyDev with Anaconda [here](https://github.com/mikec964/chelmbigstock/wiki/Set-up-Eclipse-(PyDev)-to-use-Anaconda-with-Python-2.7-and-3.x). Once you get the hang of it, anaconda environments will be an asset because they are quite powerful.

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what had worked for me. I'm sure you're right, but as I'm only doing some scientific programming, it feels like I'm using too many powerful frameworks already that I only understand a fraction of...

Comment: I'm in the same field and I would recommend becoming an expert with Anaconda first because it's perfect for scientific work and from my experience, people doing scientific work are the worst when it comes to managing and standardizing dependencies. You'll find a python repository on Github for almost any scientific paper with no guide on how to install dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

**conda** is a packaging tool and installer that aims to do more than what pip can do; handle library dependencies outside of the Python packages as well as the Python packages themselves. Conda also creates a virtual environment, like virtualenv does. For creating virtualenv with conda, use the following command:-

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

Use the following to activate the virtualenv in conda

```
source activate yourenvname
```

Then, you can install the packages in virtualenv using conda as:-

```
conda install -n yourenvname [package]
```

To Deactivate use:-

```
source deactivate
```

And to delete a no longer needed virtualenv, use :-

```
conda remove -n yourenvname -all
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but you don't need to use conda to install HoloPy. This is just the least technical option. Otherwise, you need to be able to compile HoloPy's fortran components yourself, which is fairly straightforward on Unix-based systems but complicated on Windows. Instructions can be found in HoloPy's documentation at https://holopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/dev_tutorial.html.

We are also working on putting together a singularity container distribution of HoloPy. Let me know if this is of interest to you and I will make it a priority.